# Automatically add sent / recevied emails to a Trello card using IFTTT

Tags: trello, email, if-this-then-that

I'm looking for a simple CRM, we currently use a Trello board as a CRM system which works pretty well. We create a card for each lead and then have various columns for various pipeline stages.

The one thing I would like to do is be able to sync our Trello CRM with our email client (Gmail / G Suite for Business). So that any new emails sent or received to clients would automatically be added to their Trello card. Is that possible?

Perhaps by using the custom fields function in Trello and setting one of the custom fields as an email address?